# Django media returns the 404 NOT FOUND when I try to GET media using Axios

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, django-urls

I'm trying to get media from django but I get this 404 NOT FOUND error message in the console
xhr.js?1a5c:244

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/$%7Bcategory_slug%7D/$%7Bproduct_slug%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

My product/urls.py code is this

```
from product import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('latest-products/', views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
    path('products/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.ProductDetail.as_view()),
]
```

the first path works perfectly but the second one shows this error
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/$%7Bcategory_slug%7D/$%7Bproduct_slug%7D 404 (Not Found)

My product/views.py is

```
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

class LatestProductsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all()[0:4]
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class ProductDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, category_slug, product_slug):
        try:
            return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=category_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
            
    def get(self, request, category_slug, product_slug, format=None):
        product = self.get_object(category_slug, product_slug)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

my router code for index.js is

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import Product from '../views/Product.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/AboutView.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/:category_slug/:product_slug/',
    name: 'Product',
    component: Product
  }
  
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: What is your implementation of `ProductDetail`?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should be in the format `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/test/test/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/products/test/test/` where you should replace the `test` values with correct slug values. You are trying to pass `${category_slug}` as text instead of its value. Please check the URL constructor inside your Vue project.